# move hard-drive from /dev/sdb1 to /dev/sdc1

Tags: bash, script, mount, dev, umount

During a backup procedure in a *bash script*, I should remount a hard-drive mounted on `dev/sdb1` onto `dev/sdc1`.

I am able to `umount /dev/sdb1`, but then I loose track of the device. After shutting down the machine it will be mounted on `/dev/sdc1` because of an entry in `/etc/fstab`

Is there a simple way to reassign  `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdc1` without shut-down?

Comment: What do you mean "reassign"? Do you want to change the device name?

Comment: yes, it shoud then be seen on /dev/sdc1

Comment: If you want to access the drive at `/dev/sdc1`, you could just create a symbolic link by executing the following command `# ln -s /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`. That doesn't actually rename the device (`$ lsblk` still lists the partition as `/dev/sdb1`), but in a script you can now refer to the partition as `/dev/sdc1` (e.g. `# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`).

Comment: But I'd advice you to refer to a device using it's [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) in a script, because a device name like `/dev/sda` isn't persistent, meaning that it could change on for example a reboot. In contrast a UUID never changes. You can find out the UUID of a partition using the following command: `# blkid /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029) here.

Your problem is not about renaming the device - it's about configuring fstab properly so that mounting always works, no matter what names are assigned to devices. That's *the* solution, because name assignment isn't reliable. Names can change for example if you have an external hard drive connected on boot.

The solution is to use partition UUIDs, filesystem UUIDs, partition names or filesystem names, depending on what makes more sense for your use case.

Use `blkid` to check available identifiers for a device. Here's an example from my computer:

```
# blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="9f3343e4-e078-460c-96af-aa78ab3a3b0f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="pop1804_os" PARTUUID="1c79ae2c-6d1b-4656-b6fa-b4419eccd234"
```

Depending on filesystem and partition table type you could see some of these usable identifiers:

- `UUID`: filesystem UUID
- `LABEL`: filesystem label
- `PARTUUID`: partition UUID (GPT only)
- `PARTLABEL`: partition name (GPT only)

`UUID` and `LABEL` will change when a partition is formatted, but not when it's cloned. `PARTUUID` and `PARTLABEL` are the opposite, they will not change during formatting but may during cloning because they are not a part of the filesystem.

You can replace device name in fstab with an identifier returned by `blkid`, without quotes. For example you could replace `/dev/sdb1` with `UUID=9f3343e4-e078-460c-96af-aa78ab3a3b0f`.

Use `mount -a` to test your fstab before rebooting. Make sure to unmount filesystems that you're testing first because `mount` will skip these fstab lines if they're already mounted, even if a different device is attached at a given mount point.

---

Relevant except from [`man fstab`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html):

> **The first field (fs_spec).**
>
> LABEL= or UUID= may be given instead of a device name.  This is the recommended method, as device names are often a coincidence of hardware detection order, and can change when other disks are added or removed.  For example, `LABEL=Boot' or `UUID=3e6be9de-8139-11d1-9106-a43f08d823a6'.  (Use a filesystem-specific tool like e2label(8), xfs_admin(8), or fatlabel(8) to set LABELs on filesystems).
>
> It's also possible to use PARTUUID= and PARTLABEL=. These partitions identifiers are supported for example for GUID Partition Table (GPT).
>
> [...]
>
> Note that mount(8) uses UUIDs as strings. The string representation of the UUID should be based on lower case
> characters.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The UUID solution will not work, as the hard disk changes every few weeks. However the label did the trick: When I am formating the harddisk, I will also do e2label.